# Why does `boost::asio::deadline_timer` allocate a `timer_queue` instance for each `deadline_timer` object?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am looking into the implementation of `boost::asio::deadline_timer`, based on boost 1.52.

As described in [the article on highscore](http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/asio.html#asio_extensions), it is implemented in three parts:

- `deadline_timer`, the i/o object
- `deadline_timer_service`, the service
- `detail::deadline_timer_service`, the service implementation

There will be a single instance of `deadline_timer_service` serving many `deadline_timer` objects. An instance of `detail::deadline_timer_service` is created for each `deadline_timer` object. Moreover, the timers are scheduled by a scheduler, which is usually a reactor (i.e. `epoll_reactor` on Linux in most cases).

There is a `timer_queue_` member of type `timer_queue` in `detail::deadline_timer_service` which is a heap that stores scheduled timers. This means that there will be one instance of `timer_queue` for each `deadline_timer` object. Multiple `timer_queue` objects can be added to the scheduler by `add_timer_queue()`, and they are managed by a class `timer_queue_set`.

My question is, why `asio` create multiple queues to handle timers? What is the drawback if we have a single timer queue instance in the scheduler that all timers can share?

Comment: I don't think this is how it's implemented in boost. 

_"Instead of just providing the skeleton, the Boost.Asio extension developed in this section is going to **resemble** the available `boost::asio::deadline_timer` object"_

Comment: @sehe I am not referring to the example in the highscore link. My question is about the `boost::asio::deadline_timer` implementation in `boost::asio`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read the code again and find my mistake. The actual relationship is as follows:

- `basic_deadline_timer` is the i/o object type, one instance for each deadline_timer;
- `deadline_timer_service` is the service type, one per `io_service`, retrieved by the constructor of `basic_io_object`;
- `detail::deadline_timer_service` is the service implementation type, one per service, hen one per `io_serive` as well. It is defined as the data member of `deadline_timer_service`;
- `detail::deadline_timer_service::implementation_type`: the implementation type of the timer, one per `deadline_timer`.

As `timer_queue_` is a member of `detail::deadline_timer_service`, it is one per `io_service` as well. Looks reasonable for me now.

The highscore link seems have merged the service implementation type and timer implementation type into one, which is a bit misleading.